# Touchpad disabled at boot?

Tags: boot, touchpad, acer

I'm setting up a client's laptop (Acer Aspire E1-431-2867), and for some reason, the touch pad is disabled on start up.

- Manually enabling it with the function key (<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd>) works just fine.
- The system dual boots between Ubuntu and Windows, and the problem only occurs in Ubuntu.
- The problem is not due to anything I installed as it was happening with the Live USB as well.
- I can't seem to find anything about this anywhere.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?
*NB:* I would like to return the system to the owner in a couple days.

Comment: Maybe the driver is blacklisted? `less /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Comment: @kos would this allow the touchpad to be enabled, though? I tested and this is not it.

Comment: Sorry, let me expand what I meant: I think the driver might be blacklisted; blacklisted drivers are listed in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, so if the touchpad's driver is listed in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` it's not going to be loaded at startup (and, on the other hand, it would load by other means such as running `insmod [driver]` or such as using an fn+FX combo)

Comment: @kos the touchpad's driver wasn't on the list.

Comment: Then I have no idea about what's going on, but since you need to return the laptop to the client fast here's a workaround, if you don't find anything better: run `acpi_listen` an hit fn+F7; note the number in the third column (for example for an output such as `hotkey ATKD 00000055 00000000` the number would be `55`); run `grep X /etc/acpi/events/*`, where `X` is the number you noted, and see which file (script) is processing the ACPI event; then just run the script at a system runlevel high enough to have the ACPI services running already (not sure if `/etc/rc.local` would be enough).

Comment: A command put in System Startup should run at a runlevel high enough to make this work, but it would work only for the user for which it has been set up.

Comment: I'll have to look into this tomorrow after I've had some rest. Could you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround would be to execute the script which toggles the touchpad on / off at a system runlevel low enough before X is up and running, to make sure that the touchpad is working before a GUI is even started. So `/etc/rc.local` should be ok, but unfortunately I can't say a definitive word on this since I don't have my Ubuntu machine handy right now, and I can't actually test this. It should be fine tough.

- Run `acpi_listen` and hit the <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> keystroke; the output should be similiar to this one:

```
hotkey ATKD NNNNNNNN 00000000
```

Where `NNNNNNNN` is the <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> keystroke's ACPI code;

- Run `grep NNNNNNNN /etc/acpi/events/*`; the filename in the output should be the filename of the file in which the <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> keystroke's ACPI code is handled;
- Open the file with a text editor;
- Look for a section like this one:

```bsh
# ...
event=hotkey (ATKD|HOTK) NNNNNNNN
action=/etc/acpi/actions/action.sh
# ...
```

Where `/etc/acpi/actions/action.sh` is the script that is executed each time the <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> keystroke is hit;

Now it's just a matter of executing the script in `/etc/rc.local`:

- Open `/etc/rc.local` with a text editor;
- Add this line to the end of the file before the `exit 0` line:

```bsh
# ...
/etc/acpi/actions/action.sh
# ...
```

That should be it. Reboot and see if the touchpad is enabled upon reboot;

In any case, if not needed, I'd suggest to remove the `set -e` command at the top of `/etc/rc.local`, or to modify the way the script is called calling e.g. a wrapper which calls the script itself and which always returns `0`, to avoid the script breaking the execution of `rc.local` due to return values different from `0`.

Comment: @RolandiXor Try `grep -r NNNNNNNN /etc/acpi/`; in my ASUS notebook I remember the ACPI scripts to be located in a different location than the "default" one, so it might be the same for Acer notebooks

Comment: It's still not enabling the touchpad on boot. It seems to be the right thing, but for some reason it's not working.

Comment: Disabling acpi works, but also enables numlock on boot O_o

Comment: @RolandiXor Have you tried running the script manually from a shell? Does it toggle the touchpad on / off? if yes the problem is probably with `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: The script, it turns out, does not even exist!

Comment: Are you available to join me on chat?

Comment: @RolandiXor Oh man! Yes, where are you at? Ask Ubuntu General room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26912/discussion-between-rolandixor-and-kos).